# os.path.getsize reports a filesize with an L at the end, why?

Tags: python, dictionary, filesize, directory

```
import os, sys

def crawlLocalDirectories(directoryToCrawl):
    crawledDirectory = [os.path.join(path, subname) for path, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(directoryToCrawl) for subname in dirnames + filenames]
    return crawledDirectory

print crawlLocalDirectories('.')

dictionarySize = {}
def getSizeOfFiles(filesToMeasure):
    for everyFile in filesToMeasure:
        size = os.path.getsize(everyFile)
        dictionarySize[everyFile] = size
    return dictionarySize

print getSizeOfFiles(crawlLocalDirectories('.'))
```

Whenever this is ran, I get the output of `{'example.py':392L}`, why? What's an L? I don't want to have to strip the L off at the end.

If I run it without adding it to a dictionary, it comes back with the filesize as `392`.

Comment: It's probably returning the file size as a long.

Comment: @xbonez -- post that as an answer -- maybe with a quick explanation of what a *long* actually *is*.

Comment: @Matthew -- Just curious, what OS is this on?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is only displayed or in interactive mode or when you get the string representation via `repr()`. As zigg wrote, you can simply ignore it. Consider this an implementation detail. It was probably usefull in time when it was important to make a difference between normal int and long int. In Python 3, there is no `L`, for example. The int is int no matter how big:

```
d:\>py
Python 3.2.1 (default, Jul 10 2011, 20:02:51) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>>> a
100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>>> ^Z

d:\>python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:24:47) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>>> a
100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000L
>>>
```

Notice the `L` by Python 2.7, but nothing similar by Python 3.2.

Comment: Ah, I see. That makes perfect sense. As a beginner, should I be learning Py3 or continue with 2.7?

Comment: It does not matter that much. The important things are the same. However, I would suggest to try both if possible. My guess is that Python 3 wins soon. Have a look at http://getpython3.com/diveintopython3/strings.html. The strings are one of the most visible differences. Python 3 is more logical, Python 2.6 is more used these days. Python 2.7 is in between.

Answer (score 8):

The trailing `L` means you have a [`long`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#typesnumeric).  You actually always have it, but `print`ing a `dict` will show printable representations of the values, including the `L` notation; however, printing a `long` itself shows only the number.

You almost certainly don't need to worry about stripping off the trailing `L`; you can use a `long` in all your calculations just as you would use an `int`.

Answer (score 2):

It' true the pepr's answer but if you realy need you can do the int() Function, it works also on big integers

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jul 24 2012, 10:05:39) 
[GCC 4.7.0 20120507 (Red Hat 4.7.0-5)] on linux2
>>> import os
>>> os.path.getsize('File3')
4099L
```

BUT if you put in the Function int() Automagically:

```
>>> int(os.path.getsize('File3'))
4099
```